# TexShop opens pdf file but not the .tex file

Tags: editors, texshop, macos

I already changed TeXShop as the default TeX application instead of TeXworks, but I see no way of editing my `.tex` file using TeXShop. Whenever I double-click a `.tex` file, it will automatically typeset the `.pdf` and I'm not able to see the code anymore. Any ideas?

Note: I am a total newbie to MacTeX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please be a bi more specific about what you mean by "double-clicking a .tex file"

Comment: Did you assign the files with extension `.tex` to TeXShop?

Comment: As it stands this can't possibly be answered: much to unclear what exactly is happening. Please add a screenshot.